# Exercise1.2.3 in Terence Tao's An introduction to measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory

If $E_1, E_2, E_3,\cdots \subset \mathbf{R}^d$ is a countable sequence of sets, then $m^{\star}(\bigcup E_n) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} m^{\star}(E_n)$,
where $m^{\star}(E) = \inf_{B_1\cup B_2\cup\cdots \cup B_n\cdots\supset E}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m(B_n) $, and $B_i$ are boxes,$m(B_i)$ are their elementary measure.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to prove this proposition?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: $m^*(E) = 0$ for all sets in your definition above. Perhaps you meant $\supset B$ instead?

Comment: yes, it's $\supset$ instead, thanks.

Comment: I have tried finite union. Although the situation seems trival.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $(\epsilon_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of positive reals such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n = \epsilon$. For all $n\in\{1, 2, ...\}$, choose a sequence of boxes $(B_{n, i})_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $E_n \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^\infty B_{n, i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty m(B_{n, i}) < m^\star(E_n) + \epsilon_n$. Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^2$ be a bijection. Then we have a sequence of boxes $(B_{f(l)})_{l=1}^\infty$ such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \subseteq \bigcup_{l=1}^\infty B_{f(l)}$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
m^\star(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \leq \sum_{l=1}^\infty m(B_{f(l)})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty m(B_{n, i}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg( m^\star (E_n) +\epsilon_n \bigg) = \epsilon + \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^\star(E_n).
\end{align*}
Since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $m^\star(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^\star(E_n)$.

Comment: thanks very much!!!!